# Problem related to "hpdftex.pdf"

Tags: compiling

I am trying to use the following template for the CV.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% personal data
\firstname{Yu,}
\familyname{Yue}
\title{University of Illinois at Chicago \newline \small{\texttt{\textbf{Homepage: {\color{web}\weblink{http://imyy.net}}}}}}
%\address{Office 719 SEO\\ 851 S. Morgan St.}{Chicago, IL}
\extrainfo{Office 719 SEO\\ 851 S. Morgan St.\\ Chicago, IL 60606}
\phone{540--yy--yueyu}
\email{yyu9 at uic.edu}
%\photo[64pt]{Yue_Yu}

\newcommand{\up}[1]{\ensuremath{^\textrm{\scriptsize#1}}}

% the ConTeXt symbol
\def\ConTeXt{%
  C%
  \kern-.0333emo%
  \kern-.0333emn%
  \kern-.0667em\TeX%
  \kern-.0333emt}
\definecolor{web}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}
%\definecolor{web}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{\textbf{Education}}
\cventry{2007--Present}{\textbf{Master of Science in
Mathematics}}{University of Illinois at Chicago}{USA}{}{ - Expected
in SUMMER 2009.\newline - Concentrate in Probability and Statistics,
over all GPA: 4.0/4.0.}
\cventry{2003--2007}{\textbf{Bachelor of Science}}{Fudan
University}{China}{}{ - Major in Mathematics and Applied
Mathematics, last two years GPA: 3.4/4.0.}
\cvitem{---}{\textsc{Undergraduate Thesis}}
\cvitem{title}{\textit{Nonstatistical Methods for Credit Scoring and
Its Applications}} \cvitem{description}{Develop three strategies for
credit scoring: linear programming, genetic algorithm and
back--propagating neural network and three model is built in MATLAB
for real data in order to evaluate their performances.}


\end{document}
```

When I compile it, the following error windows appeared:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:**
The <s>compiler</s>editor I used is WinEdt. The compiler the latex.

**Edit:**
`.log` file

```
(D:\Application\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2011/04/17 v6.82g Hyperref driver for pdfTeX


! Package hyperref Error: Version mismatch!
(hyperref)                * 2010/11/26 v6.81v: hyperref.sty
(hyperref)                * 2011/04/17 v6.82g: hpdftex.def.

See the hyperref package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.34 \Hy@VersionCheck{hpdftex.def}

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5079 strings out of 495362
 70906 string characters out of 3183239
 143237 words of memory out of 3000000
 8184 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5126 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 32i,1n,45p,768b,86s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Which compiler/command are you using exactly? Which LaTeX distribution are use using in which version? I can compile the above example using `pdflatex` with TeXLive 2010, except for the unknown `\weblink` macro.

Comment: @Martin: +1.Thanks for reading. I should have clarified this issue. I use WinEdt.

Comment: WinEdt is actually "just" the editor. It calls an compiler like `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, etc., if you press some compile button. It seems that you use the wrong compiler which doesn't support PDF output. You use the CTeX distribution I see. Is this a recent version?

Comment: @Jack: it looks like that your TeX system is really old. Please put a `\listfiles` as first line into your document and then run it again and send the file list which can be found at the end of the log file. Hit enter when the above arror appears.

Comment: @Herbert: I don't understand how to "send the file list which can be found at the end of the log file".

Comment: @Jack: your run `pdflatex <file>.tex` creates a log file `<file>.log`, which you can load into an editor and then copy the file list which can be found at the end of this file.

Comment: Maybe I had better update my editor.

Comment: @Herbert: What do you mean by "file list"? What does it look like?

Comment: @Herbert: I put it after my question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, that is the end of the log file, but running your document source without the `\listfiles` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of your driver `hpdftex.def` (v6.82g) doesn't match the version of your `hyperref` package (v6.81v).

I suggest updating `hyperref`. The current version is 6.82g (matching your driver). Use your package manager or get it from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).